# How to improve performance of spark.write for jdbc?

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks

I'm struggling with one thing. I have 700mb csv which conains over 6mln rows. After filtering it contains ~3mln.

I need to write it straight to azure sql via jdbc. It's super slow and takes 20min to input 3mln rows.

My cluster has 14gb ram and 4 cores. Here is my code.

```
(clearedDF.repartition(4)
  .write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .option("batchsize", 10000)
  .option("url", jdbcUrl)
  .option("dbtable", "dbo.weather")
  .option("user", properties["user"])
  .option("password", properties["password"])
  .mode("append")
  .save()
)
```

Is there any way to speed this process up?

Comment: look here: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#jdbc-writes

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Alex Ott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18627/alex-ott). Posting your [suggestion](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#jdbc-writes) as an answer to help community members.

"You can control the parallelism by calling  `coalesce(<N>)`  or  `repartition(<N>)`  depending on the existing number of partitions. Call  `coalesce`  when reducing the number of partitions, and  `repartition`  when increasing the number of partitions."

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val df = spark.table("diamonds")
println(df.rdd.partitions.length)

// Given the number of partitions above, you can reduce the partition value by calling coalesce() or increase it by calling repartition() to manage the number of connections.
df.repartition(10).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(jdbcUrl, "diamonds", connectionProperties)
```

For more information please refer [Azure sql using jdbc.| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases)